# What is the Rust equivalent of storing C++ std::function in a vector?

Tags: vector, lambda, rust, closures

This is the C++ equivalent of what I'm trying to achieve:

```cpp
std::vector<std::function<int(int)>> funcs;
funcs.emplace_back([](int n) -> int { return n + 1; });
int result = funcs[0](33);
```

How can I write the code above in Rust?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you do not plan on moving the function anywhere in particular, you can let type inference do the work for you within a code block and quite literally define your closure like it is a normal variable (in practice, it is - it implements either `Fn` or `FnMut`):

```
let my_lambda = |n| n+1;
println!("{}", my_lambda(33));
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=a5f0a64227f845c57597df40a9f11ee7)

If you intend to move this lambda out of the stack, you will need to box it:

```
let my_lambda: Box<dyn Fn(u32) -> u32> = Box::new(|n| n + 1);
println!("{}", my_lambda(33));
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=c3d8c94fcc774518cc78734cebf17985)

The principle here remains the same, the only real difference is that the lambda is now on the heap.

Storing them in a `Vec` then becomes relatively straightforward, as by now we've proven that they're "normal" types. Nothing prevents you from creating a vector of closures, but you will need to box them (`Vec` requires each element to be `Sized`, and there is no way to target two different closures by signature) and they will need to have the same signature:

```
let my_vector: Vec<Box<dyn Fn(u16) -> u16>> = vec![
    Box::new(|i| i + 1),
    Box::new(|i| i - 1),
];
println!("{}", my_vector[0](33))
```

If they have disparate signatures, you will need to write your own structure to contain them and bucket them by signature, and it is not a simple task.

---

The benchmark case:

- C++:

  ```cpp
  #include <vector>
  #include <iostream>
  #include <functional>
  int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    std::vector<std::function<int(int)>> funcs;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
      funcs.push_back([&] (int n) { return n + 1; });
      int result = funcs[i](33);
    }
  }
  ```
- Rust:

  ```
  fn main() {
     let mut lambdas:Vec<Box<Fn(u32) -> u32>> = vec![];
     for i in 0..10000000 {
       lambdas.push(Box::new(|i| i+1));
       lambdas[i](3);
     }
  }
  ```

Compilation options:

- G++: `-O3 --std=c++0x`
- Cargo: `--release`

The results:

- C++ peak heap size:

  ```
  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    n        time(i)         total(B)   useful-heap(B) extra-heap(B)    stacks(B)
  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   68    383,911,899      268,512,208      268,508,160         4,048            0
   69    555,878,425      805,387,160      805,379,072         8,088            0
   70    765,593,697      805,387,160      805,379,072         8,088            0
  ```
- Rust peak heap size:

  ```
  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    n        time(i)         total(B)   useful-heap(B) extra-heap(B)    stacks(B)
  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   46    210,486,321      268,440,920      268,436,765         4,155            0
   47    210,486,371      268,440,976      268,436,805         4,171            0
   48    210,486,496      268,441,064      268,436,885         4,179            0
  ```

The conclusions:

- C++ `std::function` wrappers are heap-allocated. The raw lambda itself that it contains is stack-allocated, and this behavior is consistent with Rust
- Rust is better at memory optimization, consuming a third of the heap size of C++
- Rust is also faster in terms of raw time

Comment: If I understand correctly, `Box` will allocate each lambda on the heap, so here we have the vector allocated on the heap, and each element also allocated on the heap, in contrast to C++ where the lambdas are not heap-allocated (just the vector itself). Is that it?

Comment: It's a bit more complicated than this. The `Vec` itself is on the stack; its internal pointer to the content is on the heap; and the lambdas themselves are on the heap (they're elements of the `Vec`, after all).

Comment: Yes, I understand this. What I mean is that the C++ version seems more efficient, because it only does 1 allocation: the vector content. The Rust version actually allocs a vector of **pointers**,then it allocs each lambda in the heap **again**, storing the pointers in the vector. That's how I see it.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're wrong about `std::function` being stored on the stack. Beyond small object optimization, they're on the heap as well, AFAIK. That said, eyeballing a function isn't a good way to benchmark performance, either, as there's two layers of optimizations happening below the hood for both C++ and rust.

Comment: @Rodrigo I've run a quick `valgrind` benchmark to get to the bottom of this. Rust allocates less than C++ on the heap, and your lambdas also go on the heap in C++. Editing the answer with the full details

Comment: "but you will need to box them" – this is not true in general. If the closures don't capture any local variables, they can be coerced to function pointers, and you can store them in a vector directly: `let v: Vec<fn(i32) -> i32> = vec![|n| n + 1, |n| n - 1];`.

Comment: Could anyone share the command/way to get the benchmark data? I would like to reproduce by myself and I suspect the slowness in C++ is because the lambda s have been copied into the vector. So there are more heap allocations in C++.

Comment: @SébastienRenauld The place of allocation here is irrelevant. And your C++ code is less optimal by redundant `[&]`. However, even this is not optimized away, the small object optimization should kick in. If not, you'd probably report a bug to your `std` vendor. Besides the weak reasoning, please make sure your benchmark reproducible with full configuration of the environment and the commands you've used.

Comment: @SvenMarnach This also less irrelevant here. C++'s lambdas with empty capture (`[]`) can do the same, or even better (empty objects v. converting to function pointers) in space efficiency. And this is hardly "in general": if the user can always use the capture-less closures, why not function pointers (or function references, `reference_wrapper` to functions...) at the very first place? When `std::function` is a necessity, there should be some need to erase the type of the concrete closure instance. There is nothing different in Rust.

Comment: @FrankHB I'm not quite sure what exactly you describe as "less irrelevant". My comment was that you don't need to box closures in Rust if they don't capture anything. I think it's helpful to mention this here for people with that use case, regardless of what the OP's use case was. I didn't intend to make any comparison to C++. Maybe you are reading something into my comment I didn't say? (I also didn't say that not boxing closures is a general solution. I said that it's not true in general that you need to box closures, since there are cases when you don't need to box them.)

Comment: @SvenMarnach For users who have confident need of `std::function`, they _should_ have learnt why function pointers/references... are not sufficient, and the shortcoming of capture-less lambdas is one of the reasons. This is _exactly the same in Rust_, so your proposal will not help much: it also defeats the main purpose to use a type-erased wrapper (`function` in C++, `Box` in Rust). The OP's code is not at a good quality to reflect the idiomatic practice (avoiding `function` if simpler types are sufficient), though. Your caveats can be more appropriate in the comments of the question.

Comment: ... and surely "less irrelevant" is a typo... it should be "less relevant".